# CSS menu in IE7 not showing full content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have spend a weeks on stackoverflow searching a solution to my problem.
Could you please check the fiddle in IE7? It's working perfectly in other and newer browsers.
Navigate as follows:
Center life / sport / "here is the problem"

http://jsfiddle.net/6m3f3/1/

Thank you for any answer which could help me.

These are company intranet sites, so sorry, i had to use fiddle.

```
.menu-left{
width: 175px;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-left ul {
float: left;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1;
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #FF7200;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;


menu-left a, .menu-left a:visited {
display: block;
width: 160px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-indent: 15px; /* text position from left in first UL*/
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
```

Just a sampe, complete code on jsFiddle